# Merge two row in SSRS

Tags: mysql, ssrs-2008

there any ways to merge row  values. suppose  emp Name is same for different month. 
for e.g

```
emp Name    Jan    Feb  Mar
a            1
a                  5
a                       9
```

I want result Like:-

```
emp Name    Jan    Feb  Mar
a            1     5     9
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `MAX`:

```
SELECT `emp Name`,MAX(Jan) as Jan,MAX(Feb) as Feb, MAX(Mar) as Mar
FROM TableName
GROUP BY `emp Name`
```

Learn more about the aggregate function `MAX()` [**here**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max).